# How to post form located in another form in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a sub-form in main form like

```
<form method="post" action="/books/addbook" id="mainForm">
 //some controls....
 <form method="post" action="/books/addbookAuthor" id="subForm">
   //some controls......
   <input type="submit" value="Add author" id="submit_subForm" />
   //some controls......
 </form>
 //some controls....
 <input type="submit" value="Add author" id="submit_mainForm" />
</form>
```

What I want is when user click "submit_subForm" only the "subForm" submit not the "mainForm".
How can I do that????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML itself does not allow for nested forms so you won't be able to do this.